# Duplicar registro ao salvar dados de um formulário em vba/useform

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Boa tarde amigos,

Como faço para duplicar um registro em uma planilha com dados salvos a partir do useform. Sendo mais específico, vou usar um exemplo de um plano de saúde onde eu tenha um formulário que cadastre titular e dependentes e precise salvar cada dependente em uma linha diferente com o titular na coluna seguinte (ou anterior) a exemplo da imagem.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que seria duplicar? Seria copiar e colar em outra planilha?

Comment: Amigo, sugiro não duplicar esses dados... mas simplesmente colocar em tabelas diferentes com um número de id ou algo assim. Mas se quiser duplicar, pode pegar o mesmo código que faz para gravar a linha do titular e criar uma função para que ao inserir o dependente pegar inserir na coluna de titular o nome desejado. Qual código está usando hoje para gravar esses dados na planilha?

Comment: Duplicar seria repetir na célula de baixo o nome do mesmo titular enquanto o dependente for vinculado ao mesmo.